# How to understand "ideographic" decomposition of characters like 不 and 与

Tags: characters, character-components

I was recommended ["character decomposition database"](https://github.com/cjkvi/cjkvi-ids) on this site.

I have started to explore it and found, that some decompositions I don't understand, like

```
U+4E0D  不   ⿱一③
U+4E0E  与   ⿹②一[GTKV]   ⿻②一[J]
```

visual representation on my machine

[image]

What do these circled numbers mean? Or they are just incorrectly displayed on my machine?

Comment: Do you know how ideographic descriptions work? It should be fairly obvious what those numbers mean if you do. Some of those decompositions produce things that aren’t encoded yet, so the numbers serve as a placeholder.

Comment: I was understanding many except numbers. Now I also understand numbers and think it is obvious, but was not thinking this before. I am a newbie and idea of number of strokes didn't came to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my best guess:

> U+4E0D    不   ⿱一③

不 is a top-bottom structure ⿱, with top component "一", ③ means components with three strokes, not yet defined.

you may look at these two:

> U+4E1A    业   ⿱④一

业 is a top-bottom structure, with the top component with 4 strokes, then the bottom component "一"

> U+4E1D    丝   ⿱⿰②②一

丝 is a top-bottom, and further, the top component could be divided into left-right component. so, ②② means two components, each with two strokes, left-right relationship, on top, then bottom component is "一"

have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are the strokes remaining. E.g.

[image]

It takes 3 strokes to write

[image]

Another example:

[image]

It takes 7 strokes to write

[image]

These numbers are placeholders for things that aren't encoded.

---

That 与 example has two decompositions because the one on the right (⿻②一[**J**]) is **J**apanese, which writes that character differently.

[image]

Comment: The document that OP is looking at is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cjkvi/cjkvi-ids/master/ids.txt